# Leiningen and Ivy Repo

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a large Ivy repo, and would like to use it with leiningen. I've added : :repositories {} to my project.clj file, but it complains that it cannot load the artifact. My normal ant script points to the full url of the repo with the ivy.setting.public.xml file, but am unsure what is the correct syntax for leiningen in this case.

Can leiningen use an Ivy repo?

Comment: Looking for the answer to this also, so +1 to anyone who answers with a detailed explanation on how to make this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a shame I didn't see this sooner.

At one time [I had a branch of the Cake build tool that had almost full Ivy support](https://github.com/lrenn/cake/wiki/Ivy).  I again have a need for this, but since Cake is now deprecated [I've had to branch leiningen](https://github.com/lrenn/vine).  I only just started but it works for resolving (including configurations, exclusions, branches, etc).

Right now it's based of the lein2 preview release.  I'm not sure how much more work I'll put into it though.  I'd like to create a complementary lein-ivy plugin that could add the features of the old Cake version (publishing, dependency reports, multiple publications, etc).